# What are those bitcoin mining hardware doing 24/7?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-hardware, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-core-development, hardware-wallet

What are those hardware doing? Which open-source or closed source software to use on those? I want to buy one of those hardware for my learning and programming.

Any advise?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest technology of Antminer or rather do your research for the new ones.

Comment: I went to a demo room, they had lot of those machines i could not figure out yet what are those doing and which software is used. I want to make an open-source software using my C++/Qt/C# skills on that. Looking for where to get started

Comment: I suppose this is what you are looking for - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/miner.cpp

it's already written in C++. but as far as I know it's open source so you can tweak it in whatever language you like.

Comment: I am very curious to get started, my main goal is to make something free for community using rasperry pi or open-source CentOS/Ubuntu/ArchLinux. Step 1) should i be first requiring a Antminer hardware? or i can without get started with regular 64-bit PC's? Step 2) Programming wont be any issue but how do you make official wallets to make the networking or connecting to shares for getting inside the business?

Comment: in my own opinion you should get your own antminer first since you're gonna tweak it's software (not budget friendly, look at the price)

secondly, you can use bitcoin-core and install it into Ubuntu/CentOS server in order for the users/clients to generate their own addresses.

Comment: @YumYumYum I think your idea is generous on behalf of people who are gonna use your Open source code, if ever. but I think it'll be a waste of time since Bitcoin itself is open source.

Comment: 1) Buy antminer (hope it has software already to use and learn and then think how to improve it) 2) Get open-source framework that is available here https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/miner.cpp and then update into custom requirements? CORRECT?

Comment: yes, but the answer is up to you, again, buying antminer just for tweaking it's sofware isnt budget friendly. you are just going to waste money.